# Model tries to use different table name in production than in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `User`. I have `pluralize_table_names` set to false so the table `User` uses is `user`. (That's kind of a mouthful!)

Interestingly, my model behaves correctly in development but in production `User` tries to use a table called `users` which doesn't exist. All my other models use their singular table names. Look at this:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> Client.table_name
=> "client"
irb(main):002:0> Appointment.table_name
=> "appointment"
irb(main):003:0> User.table_name
=> "user"
irb(main):004:0> 
$ rails console production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> Client.table_name
=> "client"
irb(main):002:0> Appointment.table_name
=> "appointment"
irb(main):003:0> User.table_name
=> "users"
irb(main):004:0>
```

As you can see, everything's fine except `User` in production. What gives?

Edit: here's the model code in production:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

And in development:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

Same exact thing. I even pointed my production instance at the same database as development and the problem persists. I started having these problems when I started using Authlogic, so I'm starting to suspect that the development environment somehow knows about some Authlogic stuff that the production environment doesn't.

Update: I tried to kill as many moving parts as possible. I set both my production environment and my development environment to point at the dev database. That didn't change anything. I changed my production environment to be a dev one and it started working. I changed my dev environment to a production one and it stopped working. This tells me there's something about the change from dev to production that makes it stop working. I have no idea what, though.

Comment: What makes this model different? Show us the code for it please.

Comment: It's the exact same in both production and development.

Comment: Are you using the same database type in development and test? I tend to use sqlite on my dev box and MySQL in production. Perhaps `user` is a reserved word for your adapter? Weird...

Comment: Not just the same database type but the very same database. I'm on PostgreSQL, by the way.

Comment: Consider using the 'Users' table then for the User model. Since you've set pluralize to false, in your User model, you can specify set_table_name :users. so in dev and prod , it will hit the users table.

Comment: Good idea. I actually had the same thought about 10 minutes ago. That works, I guess, but now the `acts_as_authentic` doesn't seem to be taking, and I'm getting `undefined method 'password' for #<User:0x2b3a2164ab50>` in my user form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. I ended up keeping the singular `user` table name in the database, but in my model, I did this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "user"
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

The directives have to be in that order or else it will not work! I don't know why that's the case (actually, if I think about it a little bit, it makes sense) and I don't know why I decided to try to switch the order but I'm glad I did.

Comment: in Rails 3 this would have to be self.table_name = "user"